# Weblogic Connection Pooling using Ecllipse

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, weblogic, connection-pooling

```
In tomcat am writing these code:



In TestServlet:  In servlet class written these code

    Context envcontext=new InitialContext();
        Context iniitContext=(Context)envcontext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
    DataSource  datasource=(DataSource)iniitContext.lookup("jdbc/Mysql");
    Connection connection=datasource.getConnection();
        Statement stmt=(Statement) connection.createStatement();
```

how to get the MySQL database jndi connection in weblogic using Ecllipse

Answer (score 1):

Well weblogic and tomcat wont differ in the way you get a connection from the pool.. but at first you need to initialize a database pool in the weblogic server by going to the Administration Console:

under your server name to the left select **Services** Then go to **Data Sources** and add a New Data source..

Please note that if you're in production mode in weblogic then you must click on lock and edit in the upper left corner and when done you should click on release configuration in the same location.. but when under development you wont need to do that..

After adding a new MySQL data source just go to java and

```
Context initialContext = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource) initialContext.lookup("THE_MYSQL_JNDI_NAME_YOU_CHOSE");
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
```

And that's it.. :-)

Comment: By the way you can find the administration console by going to the URL in your web browser: http://[host]:[port]/console